# Зачем использовать специализированные библиотеки для логирования?

Tags: c#, логирование

1. Зачем использовать специализированные библиотеки для логирования?
   (built-in tools, Serilog, NLog, log4net)
2. Правильно ли использовать try/catch внутри метода или нужно как-то глобально применять?
   try/catch использовать в каждом методе?
3. Как это работает в NET Framework, NET Core?
4. Как это использовать если просто для исследования кода  и для рабочего проекта?

---

Допустим цель: просто исследовать как работает код.
Какие, где значения образуются....
Я могу сделать класс Логер.
Сделать в этом классе метод, который будет принимать несоклько параметров и записывать в **csv** файл.
Потом этот **csv** файл в Ексель проанализировать.

Условно код.

```cs
public class Program
{
    Logger logger = new Logger();
    ProductService productService = new ProductService(logger);
}
```

```cs
public class Logger
{
    string pathCurrentFileLog = @"logger.csv";

    public void LogWriteLine(string messageFull)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(pathCurrentFileLog))
            CreateFileForLogging();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathCurrentFileLog, true))
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            string messageLog = now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd || HH:mm:ss:ffff") + " || " + messageFull; //

            sw.WriteLine(messageLog); //++ // 2022-12-15T07:02:43.5857720+03:00
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class ProductService
{
    Logger _logger;
    public ProductService(Logger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    } 
    
    public void CreateProduct()
    {        
        try
        {
            // код.....
            _logger.LogWriteLine("Пройден шаг-1");
            // код.....
            _logger.LogWriteLine("Пройден шаг-2");
            // код.....
            int i = 5;
            _logger.LogWriteLine($"int i = {i}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWriteLine($"ex.Message -- {ex.Message}");
        }
    } 
    
    public void DeleteProduct()
    {
        try
        {
            //Do something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWriteLine($"ex.Message -- {ex.Message}");
        }
    }    
}
```

## Заметка

Код

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    //NLog recommends using a static variable for the logger object
    private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    //NLog supports several logging levels, including INFO
    logger.Info("Hello {0}", "Earth");
    try
    {
        //Do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Exceptions are typically logged at the ERROR level
        logger.Error(ex, "Something bad happened");
    }
}
```

**Fatal** — used for reporting about errors that are forcing shutdown of the application.
**Error** — used for logging serious problems occurred during execution of the program.
**Warning**  — used for reporting non-critical unusual behaviour.
**Information** — used for informative messages highlighting the progress of the application for sysadmins and end users.
**Debug** — used for debugging messages with extended information about application processing.
**Verbose** — the noisiest level, used for tracing the code.

Comment: 1. Вы сами должны ответить на этот вопрос. Обычно логгирование это не просто запись в файлик, а некий уровень абстракций с подключаемыми модулями, где мы разом можем и в базу записать, и в файл, и письмо отправить, все это под каждый уровень лога, и с разным шаблоном. Хотите это писать самостоятельно - без проблем. 2. Ваш код должен быть максимально стабилен без `try/catch`, чем их меньше, тем лучше. Ну а на "глобальном" уровне вы можете ловить все "не отловленные" ошибки, и делать с ними что надо. 3. О чем речь? 4. Как хотите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём с того, что ваш код **очень** медленный.
Проверка `File.Exists` - медленная, потому что ненужная.
Отдельное создание файла `CreateFileForLogging` - медленное, потому что ненужное: конструктор `StreamWriter` сам создаст файл при его отсутствии.
При *каждом* вызове вашего метода `LogWriteLine` файл открывается и закрывается - эти операции *чудовищно* медленные!
Свойство [DateTime.Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/performance-insights-datetime-now?view=vs-2022) - тоже медленное. Лучше используйте `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Современные сервисы на платформе .NET могут обрабатывать сотни тысяч запросов в секунду! Если в таком сервисе реализовать логирование с помощью вашего кода, то производительность катастрофически упадёт.
Так становится ясна первая причина, зачем использовать специализированные библиотеки для логирования: скорость!

---

Другая причина.
Вот вы перечислили уровни логирования: `Fatal`, `Error` и пр. Используются они в вашем логгере? Нет. Можете вы добавить их использование? Причём, чтобы их можно было задавать и напрямую в коде, и из файла конфига, и динамически менять прямо в процессе выполнения? Наверное, да. Но сколько времени это у вас займёт?
А в готовых библиотеках это уже реализовано. Просто берём и используем.

---

Ваш логер пишет только в файл в одном формате. Во "взрослых" библиотеках можно писать в файл, консоль, базу данных, облачные хранилища... В самых разных форматах: csv, json, любые произвольные...
Развитые библиотеки позволяют указывать разные места логирования для разных окружений: на машине разработчика - одно (например, консоль), во время тестирования - другое (например, файл), при развёртывании на сервере - третье (БД).
Опять же, всё это можно реализовать вручную, но проще взять готовое решение.

---

Допустим, пишем в файл. За короткое время его размер может вырасти до гигабайтов. С ним станет неудобно работать.
Нормальные логгеры позволяют задавать *ротацию* файлов: например, каждый день создаётся новый; каждую неделю удаляются старые файлы и т. п.
И, опять же, всё это можно реализовать вручную. Но проще взять готовую библиотеку логирования.